# Accessing the xml values from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, xmlreader

I am using [this xmlreader](https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader). Here is my code

```
NSDictionary *xmlDict = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:responseString error:&error1];
NSLog(@"XMLData: %@",xmlDict);
```

I can save and log the data and it looks like this.

```
response =     {
        Gpn0 =         {
            text = 10000;
        };
        Gsn0 =         {
            text = 4;
        };
        btn0 =         {
            text = up;
        };        
    };
}
```

But how can I access a single element from this dictionary?

Comment: `NSDictionary *inner = rootNode[@"Gpn0"];`

Comment: @H2CO3 by rootNode, do you mean "response" from my question?

Comment: if you have a pointer to that dictionary, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *gpn0 = response[@"Gpn0"];
NSNumber *gpn0_text = gpno[@"text"]; // note this is a numeric value

NSDictionary *btn0 = response[@"btn0"];
NSString *btn0_text = gpno[@"text"]; // note this is a string value    

so on and so forth
```